# How do I run a custom query with C# .net in mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an aggregation query that I run in a mongo shell. What I want, is to execute this command from a simple console application with .Net 5.
I just want to run the command (not use any fancy LINQ queries) and loop in the results to measure somethings.

I tried a simple query:

```
 _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");  
 _database = _client.GetDatabase("zzz");  
 var res = await _database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>("users.find({})");
```

But results is always null. I haven't quite understood whether runCommand supports only built-in commands or it's more generic.
Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know much about MongoDb.

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find):

```
db.runCommand(
   {
      "find": <string>,
      // ...
   }
)
```

So it seems to me your query should be:

```
var res = await _database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>("{ find: 'users' }");
```

Comment: Is there a way to run the command excactly as I write it in the mongo shell? For example my query is like:
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{'$addFields': {'uid': {'$toString': '$_id'}}},
{'$lookup': {'from': 'profiles', 'localField': 'uid', 'foreignField': 'user_id.id', 'as': 'profile'}}
])

Comment: @Harris It's two different APIs so I wouldn't expect so. Why do you need it to be the exact same?

Comment: I wanted to make a benchmark console app to see if I can get some results (and do some stuff with the results) quicker with .net. I know OleDb commands for sql server had such a feature, and I find it odd that I cannot do the same. 
Thanks a lot